# How many partitions does my athena table have?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have this query:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS tablename;
```

Result is:

```
dt=2018-01-12
dt=2018-01-20
dt=2018-05-21
dt=2018-04-07
dt=2018-01-03
```

Do I have 5 partitions or 1, being the date? What counts towards athena's 20,000 partition limit. 5 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

I would say "it is partitioned by date, with 5 partitions" because `ADD PARTITION` is used to add a single directory. Therefore, it would could as 5 towards the 20,000 limit.

The partition is useful if you often use `WHERE DT = '2018-xx-xx'` statements in your queries, but will not particularly help otherwise. (Splitting data into multiple files does help to parallelize work, but it also comes with an overhead.)